# How can I check a function was called by another function?

Tags: c++, class, function

I am currently trying to make sure that a member function of one class is *only* called by a member function of another class.

The architecture is imposed and cannot be changed, the port means that some logic has to be done in `a.call()` before calling `b.call()`. `a.call()` therefore calls `b.call()` to simplify things and make sure the order is respected.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337855/how-to-know-what-function-called-another) to my question. Only, the problem is that I am using classes, and the two classes have the **same** member function name and so the `#define` tries to replace all the occurrences which have different prototypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head, options would be:

- Make `b.call` private and make `b` add `a` or `a.call` as a `friend`
- Turn `b.call` into a class and put the body into a a private constructor  with `a` or `a.call` as a `friend`
- grep the source code for `b.call`, make sure the only call is in `a.call`, and add a comment at the declaration saying "if you call this function you will be fired"
- Change `b.call` to take at least one of the values it needs as a parameter (even if it ignores it and uses the value from somewhere else)

Comment: Yeah the first option is what I did in the end. I'll delete my answer and accept yours.

Comment: @3nixios: Note though, that now *every* function in `a` can call `b.call()`.

Comment: @Xeo I agree that this could be problematic, but it leaves much less scope for erroneously calling `b.call`, although my question was specific, this should be good enough for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend the [passkey pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324898/can-we-increase-the-re-usability-of-this-key-oriented-access-protection-pattern). It's very good for giving fine grained control on who can do what with your function.

Comment: This is actually really cool. I wouldn't have thought of that.

Comment: @Xeo: oh that's a nice name, we struggled some a year ago and nobody would know its name, I like yours :)

Comment: @Space: I love that pattern (esp. C++0x version) and I try to spread the word whenever I can. :)

Comment: @Matthieu: If you go through that question's OP's questions, there should be one asking for a name (or one of the related questions has it), and that was the accepted answer. :) **Edit**: [Here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324248/how-to-name-this-key-oriented-access-protection-pattern).

Comment: @Xeo: yes, but dropping the friend is a nice move :) The struggle I referred to was the precise question you linked :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you change `b.call` to take a reference to `a`? This way, `b.call` can call `a.call` itself:

```
struct A {
    void call() {
        // do stuff
    }
};

struct B {
    void call(A & a) {
        a.call();
        // do stuff
    }
};
```

This makes sure that `a.call` is always called before the rest of `b.call` is executed.

Comment: +1 Yes this would be nice to keep the dependency, but by preference I find using a _friend_ class 'cleaner'.

Comment: @3nixios: They are cleaner, but the way you stated your problem, they don't exactly solve it. Any method of the friend can call the method, so you still have the possibility of calling in the wrong order.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y This is true, but for my specific useage this is good enough for the moment. Your answer is more globally acceptable, which is why I still upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a flag?

```
a.call()
{
    // ...
    flag = 1;
    b.call();
    flag = 0;
}

b.call()
{
    if (flag == 0)
        return;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This would require a shared flag between the two classes, which I don't find vto be much to my taste. Also the compile-time check provided by the friend-class is much more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you program for certain platform (say x86 or x64), and you know the calling convention (e.g. cdecl), then you can [get this info from the stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)

Say you want to check the **object** that called the function, so use the `this` pointer that is pushed to the stack prior to calling the member function: get the `this` pointer and compare it with the object that you want (`this_pointer == a`)

If you want to check certain function, get the caller address from the stack and check against that function: `caller_address == A::call`. If it's a virtual function, use the `this` pointer to get the `vtable`.

Depending on the calling-convention and the order of pushing variables on the stack, you may have to check first the input variables sizes, in order to get to the information you need.