# Get file and line of calling function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stack-trace

I'm trying to write a class that logs calls to its `operator=` but I don't know of away to do it without changing the calling code.  For a function whose signature I could adjust, something like this might work: [How to know what function called another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337855/how-to-know-what-function-called-another), but I don't see how that would work for a function like `operator=`.  Is this possible?

Example class/usage:

```
template <typename T>
class LoggingT {
    T data;
    LoggingT& operator=(const LoggingT& rhs){
        data = rhs; 
        std::cout << "assigned at line: " 
          << ???? << " in file " << ???? << std::endl;
    return *this;
};
```

Comment: You might be interested in this: [C (programming language): Is there a way to print the name of the calling function in C without passing it as an argument?](http://www.quora.com/C-programming-language/Is-there-a-way-to-print-the-name-of-the-calling-function-in-C-without-passing-it-as-an-argument)

Comment: Some operating systems allow you to get the call stack. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899870/print-call-stack-in-c-or-c) please.

Comment: FWIW, there's a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3972.pdf) that apparently got favourable reviews.

Comment: I don't see how the call stack is associated with function names.  Even if you could get the address of the jump, how does one calculate the function starting address or function name without a map?

Comment: @Thomas: Depending on the binary format of the executable (and how much info has been stripped out of it) this could be done by looking in the symbol table of the executable (ELF) or equivalent, then demangling the name using a compiler-specific library.

Comment: You'd also have to wonder how this would interact with e.g. `std::fill`, which has a pretty good idea how it's going to call `operator=`. That is to say, not with extra arguments.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3899916/1413395) of the Q&A link I gave, mentions the [`backtrace_symbols()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace_symbols) function, to get the actual function names for the addresses retrieved with `backtrace()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the backtrace_symbols() is not in every compiler.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews As I mentioned _Some operating systems_ :P ...